# How can I automaticly color a cell based on another cells content that I know?

Tags: excel, formatting

I´m trying to fill a Cell based on the words "beim Baum." which could appear in different cells in the same line. If this is true for any cell I want a particular cell to turn yellow. All cells contain words or numbers and are formatted as numbers. 
So for example cell A1 contains "beim Baum." so I would like B1 to turn yellow. it should also turn yellow if C1 contains "beim Baum."

I know the conditional formatting formula for filling in a cell based on an exact word would be Rule $A1="beim Baum." Applies to =$B1, but this does not work.
I also tried: =SEARCH("beim Baum.",$B1)
and: =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("beim Baum.",$B1))

No matter which formula nothing happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISNUMBER SEARCH approach is correct.

Lets have complete example:

[image]

Conditional formatting rule based on formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("beim baum",$A1&$C1))
```

is applied to `=$B$1:$B$8`.

Comment: Did not work. What was wrong? <a href="https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-2e108b-1547448451.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.bilder-upload.eu/thumb/2e108b-1547448451.png" border="1" alt="Bilder-Upload.eu - share DEINE Bilder" /></a>

Comment: @KathyWeb: First, formulas should not be wraped in single quotes. Second, in German Excel the formula will be `=ISTZAHL(SUCHEN("beim Baum";$AB6&$AF6))`. Note the semicolon as arguments delimiter instead of comma.